# Undefined is not an object (evaluating RNRandomBytes.seed)

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, npm, react-native

Long story short, I'm trying to develop an iOS app using React-Native for the front-end and MySQL for the back.

After installing the mysql module and install rn-nodeify, I wastold that I'm missing module A. After installing module A and reloading, I am missing B. After B, then C, etc etc etc. After getting past the modules, I get this error:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating RNRandomBytes.seed)`

Then, I installed RNPM and ran "`rnpm link`. Now, my app will not build and shows this error.

[image]

Am I doing something that is just fundamentally wrong, or is it this much of a pain to install the mysql module?

This also happened to me when I tried PostgreSQL.

Comment: Just to be clear: when you say `MySQL for the back` You're running `mysql` on a node server that you will communicating with via `HTTP` requests? If instead you are attempting to install MySQL on the iOS device, you might run into some difficulties. Let me know which one your attempting, and maybe I can provide a better answer.

Comment: My end goal is to host the MySQL server on AWS and interact with it from the app. From looking at the mysql node package, I think this does not involve HTTP requests. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: OK, that's what I was trying to determine. I've added an answer, please let me know if still not understanding your setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I was doing something very fundamentally wrong. I was completely missing the middleman that is a backend server (lol). I have set up an Express server to interact with the database and have gotten it working.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something that is just fundamentally wrong, or is it this much of a pain to install the mysql module? (This also happened to me when I tried PostgreSQL)

Maybe. React Native should be though of as purely client code. Similarly to how you would separate your web code from backend code.

The MySQL node module is designed to run in [Node](https://nodejs.org). [Node](https://nodejs.org) is separate environment. Generally you can use one `package.json` file and one `node_modules` directory for both your server side and client code. As long as your careful not to import server code, i.e. code designed to run in node, into your client code.

Sometimes you run into versioning problems and it's best to have a separate directory with separate `package.json` file for the server code.

If I still don't understand your setup. Please update your question to include your directory structure, where you're calling the mysql module, and how you are running that script.